# How many memory need neo4j to store a relationship?

Tags: neo4j

I have a lot of nodes and relationships to store to Neo4J.
I have 300k nodes and 10k different relationships types. So, let's say two nodes are linked by the 10k different relationships, I will have 3 billion relationships to store.

I wonder how many memory use one relationship in Neo4J. The relationship has no properties and its name is just a number with 6 digits max.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-caches.html#_object_cache and more specifically under "Heap memory usage"